# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath open View inbetween cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I am trying to make it so that when i select a cell in my UITableView, it opens a view underneath that cell with text in it

i found an example of a website that does this to make it clearer for you...

http://www.impactonhold.co.uk/faq.html

does anyone know if this is possible on the iPhone/iPad, and if there are any examples out there.

I have googled, but with no success.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add one more entry to the data source of your table view. Then you can call 
`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` `to insert a new cell.

You can find some help in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)